# How to prevent eclipse formatter from removing "alignment spaces" in block comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

We are using a (slightly adopted) version of the "Java style" from google, by simply importing the corresponding XML within eclipse (from [here](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml)).

That works nicely, but we see one annoying problem with block comments.

Our files do have a generated copyright header, looking like:

```
/* some text followed by some spaces      */
/* so that all lines are equally spaced   */
```

When using the google style xml, the above turns into

```
/* some text followed by some spaces */
/* so that all lines are equally spaced */
```

When formatting with the `Eclipse [built-in]` formatter, the spaces aren't removed!

I carefully checked the google XML file, and ran into this line:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_block_comments" false="true"/>
```

But alas, changing that line to use `false` doesn't change anything.

Q: how to modify that google style XML file so that spaces stay within block comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse [built-in] style has 'Enable header comment formatting' turned off (the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.format_header` value in the XML). So it is leaving the header comment alone.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the quick comeback! And I am glad I can contribute to your path to 100K ;-)